# Declare class with name from string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Is there any way to declare class with name that I have stored in string variable in Python?

```
class_name = "User"

class [class_name]:

    def hello():
        return "world"
```

Comment: Use [exec](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/).

Comment: You can use `namedtuple` from `collections` module

Comment: @sanitizedUser But you have to check user input first. Because if it is not an appropriate class name, you might have a `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* pass a string to [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) and get a class back if you use the three-argument form of `type`.

As the docs say:

> With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a
> dynamic form of the class statement.

Now, whether this is a good solution for your problem, I'll leave up to you...

```
class_name = "User"

def hello(self):
    return self.class_attr + " world"

AClass = type(class_name, (object,), {'class_attr': 'something', 'hello':hello})
  
a = AClass()

print(a)
# <__main__.User object at 0x7fc0cb29bb10>

print(a.class_attr)
# something

print(a.hello())
# 'something world'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `namedtuple` like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
class_name = "User"
a = namedtuple(class_name, "attr1, attr2, hello")
print(a)     #   <class '__main__.User'>
obj = a(1, 2, lambda: print("hello world!"))
print(obj)   # User(attr1=1, attr2=2, hello=<function <lambda> at 0x00000241E2FA4B88>)
obj.hello()  # hello world!
```

Comment: Some important differences between an object and a tuple will become apparent when you try to either add a method (like the OP's `hello()`) or change one of the attributes.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I agree it is somehow limited than classes. However, we can easily implement methods: see my update. I added `hello` method.

Comment: You've added a static function, not a method. A method would allow you to use the state of the object — for example to print one of the attributes or to sum the attributes, etc...

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes I agree, but we can emulate a method by defining a lambda function with 1 parameter. And whenever we call it, we give to it the object.

It is not like real class, but it might work.